# PayPal Chained Payments

Tags: paypal

I am trying to use the PayPal Chained Payments APIs. What I am trying to find out is can I have multiple Receiver 2 where if I am online store and all I do is basically help them sell stuff, I can manage the receiver 2 payments according to the sale.

For example in my store I have two sellers

1. Sells shoes
2. Sells shirts

Is it possible to create a config file where the sellers can sign up and put in the necessary information which is automatically accepted by the system and the payments are done via chained payments API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is one of the ways people use Chained Payments the most.

When people create an account to sell on your site you can have them enter their PayPal account email address into their control panel.  Then when an order occurs with various sellers on it (you could split payments with up to 6 receivers) you simply add each receiver into the API request accordingly.

When the payment occurs each receiver will get the amount you specified that they should receive, so of course you'll need to handle all of the logic to build this request based on the item(s) in the shopping cart when the buyer checks out.