# Paypal chained payment - different primary receivers

Tags: paypal, payment, chain

From other posts it seems it is possible to determine different secondary receivers depending on the product that is being sold: [PayPal Chained Payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001854/paypal-chained-payments). (I'm assuming this is correct)

But is it possible to determine different primary receivers for each sale and keep the secondary receiver(s) the same?

Thanks,
Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

You specify "each sale". You can certainly set up a chained payment to include a different Primary receiver in "transaction B" than you did in "transaction A".

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Kevin, really helpful.